# MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync() Always Asking for Permission Despite Being Granted in Android 11 Emulator

Tags: react-native, expo, android-emulator, android-permissions, media-library

I'm encountering an issue with MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync() in an Android 11 emulator. Even when the user has already granted the requested permission, this function consistently asks for permission, resulting in an unwanted permission prompt.

I'm handling permissions as follows:

```
const perm = await MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync();
  if (!perm.granted) {
    const perm = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
  }

  try {
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
    const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Download');
    if (album == null) {
      await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Download', asset, false);
    } else {
      await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
  }
```

Expectation:

If the user has already granted the required permissions, MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync() should not prompt for permission again. The app should proceed with the provided actions as permissions are already granted.

Actual:

Despite the user having granted permissions, MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync() consistently asks for permission, leading to an unnecessary permission prompt.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expo version? I'm exp 47, and the same thing happens again.
After searching, it seems that upgrading to 48 will solve the problem. (I haven't tried it yet)
please note.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15273#issuecomment-1545943670

Comment: Why don't you test and update your answer with your own experience? "*this might work*" is not as strong as "*I've used this and it solved my problem*".

Comment: You are right, I purely wanted to be helpful to the questioner. If it doesn't help, I'll take my answer down.

Comment: Truely thanksful for the answer. We just changed the tech stacks from expo to java inevitavely. I will try with version 48 and get back to you again. Thank you!

Comment: As you can see it indeed was helpful. But "I did not try, maybe ..." is still not a good answer according to [answer]. The proposal should habe been a comment, the solution after confirmation could then have been an answer, but still a less convincing one than "I tested this and it works.".